# Need help extending a function and for loop in R

Tags: r, function, for-loop, dataframe

I have the following function with a for loop:

```
getSequences <- function(input.seq){
peptide.result <- c()
for (i in 1:nrow(peptides.df)) {
    peptide.seq <- substr(input.seq, peptides.df$StartAA[i], peptides.df$EndAA[i])
    peptide.info <- data.frame(cbind(peptide.name = peptides.df$Name[i], peptide.seq)) 
    peptide.result <- rbind(peptide.result, peptide.info)
}  
    return(peptide.result)
}

test.results <- getSequences(input.seq)
```

The function takes an amino acid sequence and then using this input and a matrix of peptides with start and stop positions, it extracts a subset of the sequence at different postions to generate a set of peptides. 
sequence:

example amino acid sequence:

```
input.seq <- ("MRKLYCVLLLSAFEFTYMINFGRGQNYWEHPYQNSDVYRPINEHREHPKEYEYPLHQEHTYQQE")
```

Here is what the first few rows of peptides.df looks like:

```
   Name StartAA EndAA
peptide_1   25    48
peptide_2   33    56
peptide_3   41    64
```

Current Output peptide.result:

```
peptide.name    peptide.sequence
peptide_1   QNYWEHPYQNSDVYRPINEHREHP
peptide_2   QNSDVYRPINEHREHPKEYEYPLH
peptide_3   INEHREHPKEYEYPLHQEHTYQQE
```

How can I extend it to take a dataframe which has the sample# and its input sequence.  For each sample# and its sequence, I want to generate a set of peptides just like a did for the example.

new input: data frame with sample_sequences (200 samples with input sequences)

```
sample1     MRKLYCVLLLSAFEFTYMINFGRGQNYWEHPYQNSDVYRPINEHREHPKEYEYPLHQEHTYQQE
sample2     MRKLYCVLLLSAFEFTYMINFGRGQNYWEHPYQNSDVYRPINEHREHPKEYEYPLHQEHTYQQE
sample3     MRKLYCVLLLSAFEFTYMINFGRGQNYWEHPYQNSDVYRPINEHREHPKEYEYPLHQEHTYQQE
...
sample200   MRKLYCVLLLSAFEFTYMINFGRGQNYWEHPYQNSDVYRPINEHREHPKEYEYPLHQEHTYQQE
```

new output: sample_peptides

```
sample1 peptide_1   QNYWEHPYQNSDVYRPINEHREHP
sample1 peptide_2   QNSDVYRPINEHREHPKEYEYPLH
sample1 peptide_3   INEHREHPKEYEYPLHQEHTYQQE
sample2 peptide_1   QNYWEHPYQNSDVYRPINEHREHP
sample2 peptide_2   QNSDVYRPINEHREHPKEYEYPLH
sample2 peptide_3   INEHREHPKEYEYPLHQEHTYQQE
sample3 peptide_1   QNYWEHPYQNSDVYRPINEHREHP
sample3 peptide_2   QNSDVYRPINEHREHPKEYEYPLH
sample3 peptide_3   INEHREHPKEYEYPLHQEHTYQQE
...
sample200   peptide_1   QNYWEHPYQNSDVYRPINEHREHP
sample200   peptide_2   QNSDVYRPINEHREHPKEYEYPLH
sample200   peptide_3   INEHREHPKEYEYPLHQEHTYQQE
```

Comment: on a high level you just want a another loop around your `getSequences` function. `for (s in sample_sequences) {getSequences()}`, right?

Comment: `sapply(df$sample_sequences,getSequences)` should do this, although the output format will be slightly different.

Comment: Hi Everyone, Thank you for your help. I ended up changing my approach to the problem to do user requirements.  However, I am using each of your suggestions as I am trying to learn R programming. My new approach is to subset the input sequences based on two coordinates (Coord1, Coord2) entered by user.      library(dplyr) subset.sample.seq <- sample_sequences %>% mutate(Sequence = subset(Sequence, Coord1, Coord2)

Comment: Here is my new code shown properly:   `library(dplyr)
subset.sample.seq <- sample_sequences %>%
  mutate(Sequence = substr(Sequence, Coord1, Coord2))`

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid loops with `tidyr` and `dplyr`. You can use `crossing` to expand sample_sequences for all possible peptides.df. Then, it's just a simple `mutate` using `substr`

```
library(dplyr);library(tidyr)
peptides.df <- read.table(text="   Name StartAA EndAA
peptide_1   25    48
peptide_2   33    56
peptide_3   41    64",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

sample_sequences <-read.table(text=" sample sequence
sample1     MRKLYCVLLLSAFEFTYMINFGRGQNYWEHPYQNSDVYRPINEHREHPKEYEYPLHQEHTYQQE
sample2     MRKLYCVLLLSAFEFTYMINFGRGQNYWEHPYQNSDVYRPINEHREHPKEYEYPLHQEHTYQQE
sample3     MRKLYCVLLLSAFEFTYMINFGRGQNYWEHPYQNSDVYRPINEHREHPKEYEYPLHQEHTYQQE",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

crossing(sample_sequences,peptides.df)%>%
  mutate(peptide.sequence=substr(sequence, StartAA, EndAA))

   sample                                                         sequence      Name StartAA EndAA         peptide.sequence
1 sample1 MRKLYCVLLLSAFEFTYMINFGRGQNYWEHPYQNSDVYRPINEHREHPKEYEYPLHQEHTYQQE peptide_1      25    48 QNYWEHPYQNSDVYRPINEHREHP
2 sample1 MRKLYCVLLLSAFEFTYMINFGRGQNYWEHPYQNSDVYRPINEHREHPKEYEYPLHQEHTYQQE peptide_2      33    56 QNSDVYRPINEHREHPKEYEYPLH
3 sample1 MRKLYCVLLLSAFEFTYMINFGRGQNYWEHPYQNSDVYRPINEHREHPKEYEYPLHQEHTYQQE peptide_3      41    64 INEHREHPKEYEYPLHQEHTYQQE
4 sample2 MRKLYCVLLLSAFEFTYMINFGRGQNYWEHPYQNSDVYRPINEHREHPKEYEYPLHQEHTYQQE peptide_1      25    48 QNYWEHPYQNSDVYRPINEHREHP
5 sample2 MRKLYCVLLLSAFEFTYMINFGRGQNYWEHPYQNSDVYRPINEHREHPKEYEYPLHQEHTYQQE peptide_2      33    56 QNSDVYRPINEHREHPKEYEYPLH
6 sample2 MRKLYCVLLLSAFEFTYMINFGRGQNYWEHPYQNSDVYRPINEHREHPKEYEYPLHQEHTYQQE peptide_3      41    64 INEHREHPKEYEYPLHQEHTYQQE
7 sample3 MRKLYCVLLLSAFEFTYMINFGRGQNYWEHPYQNSDVYRPINEHREHPKEYEYPLHQEHTYQQE peptide_1      25    48 QNYWEHPYQNSDVYRPINEHREHP
8 sample3 MRKLYCVLLLSAFEFTYMINFGRGQNYWEHPYQNSDVYRPINEHREHPKEYEYPLHQEHTYQQE peptide_2      33    56 QNSDVYRPINEHREHPKEYEYPLH
9 sample3 MRKLYCVLLLSAFEFTYMINFGRGQNYWEHPYQNSDVYRPINEHREHPKEYEYPLHQEHTYQQE peptide_3      41    64 INEHREHPKEYEYPLHQEHTYQQE
```